# Design question in WPF .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, design-patterns

Event Management
An event is an entity which can be triggered when specified condition is met. User creates an event giving following inputs:

1. Event Name
2. Event Type ( event can be categorized )
3. Based on event type there is a condition which user has to specify. This condition is  a criterion for raising the event.
4. Event has Notification methods like: SMS, Email , Playing sound etc. And user is 
   notified by whichever notification user has specified.

User may specify all notification methods, it means user is notified through SMS, email and playing sound when event is raised condition is met.
Think of a wizard to enter all the above. Please suggest me a flexible design to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Udi Dahan has written two excellent articles ([on his blog](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) and [for MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236415.aspx)) on the **Domain Event Pattern** which sounds like it will fit your purpose.

The Domain Event Pattern does have its downsides; with the most common complaint being that it's difficult to find out what events have been subscribe to and it can become unmanageable. That being said I've used it before and would highly recommend it.